# R - find highest value in column and set it to others

Tags: r, dataframe, max

I have a huge dataframe - more than 1000 columns, 20000 rows.

```
   id      a        b        c        d
1  42      3       NA       NA       NA
2  42     NA        6       NA       NA
3  42     NA       NA        7       NA
```

The goal is to find highest value for each column. The only way how to know do that is via mutate, but since there are so much column, it is impossible to write for each column separately.

Result should looks like this. Please note that for some columns is highest value NA.

```
   id      a        b        c        d
1  42      3        6        7       NA
```

Comment: Or use `sort`: `sapply(df, function(x) sort(x)[1])`

Comment: @markus `sort` is much better option for this case. Handles the `NA` case well. Neat and crisp.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your date is called `df`, you can use `base` R to accomplish it:

```
df2 <- sapply(df1, function(x) max(x, na.rm = T))
df2
#id    a    b    c    d 
#42    3    6    7 -Inf 

is.na(df2) <- sapply(df2, is.infinite)
#id  a  b  c  d 
#42  3  6  7 NA
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df <- read.table( text = "   id      a        b        c        d
1  42      3       NA       NA       NA
                  2  42     NA        6       NA       NA
                  3  42     NA       NA        7       NA", header = TRUE)

library(dplyr)
summarise_all(df, funs( max( ., na.rm = TRUE ) ) )

  id a b c    d
1 42 3 6 7 -Inf
```

if you want, change -inf to NA